# cxGrid 6 FocusedRecordChanged want to know if FocusedItemChanged

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I have the GotToNextCellOnEnter and the FocuscellOnCycle properties set to true. When I press enter on the last cell the FocusedRecordChanged event fires and then the FocusedItemChanged event fires. Is there a way of detecting that the FocusedItemChanged event is due to fire from within the FocusRecordChanged event. I am trying to use these events stop the user from focusing on specific cells. I want to ignore the FocusedRecordChanged event if the FocusedItemChanged event is going to fire just after it. Ideally what I want is a FocusedCellChanged event but there is not one of these.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the help for the ExpressQuantumGrid Suite 6 the OnFocusedRecordChanged

> Occurs after focus is moved to a different record.

and the OnFocusedItemChanged

> Occurs when focus is changed to a different View item.

where an *Item* is a column.

That means that (with your current configuration, i.e., GoToNextCellOnEnter and FocusCellOnCycle set to true) everytime you leave *pressing the Enter key* the last column of a record both events will *always* fire since you are moving to the first item of the next record.

EDIT: In the case of leaving with the Down key it is absolutely normal that the OnFocusedItem does not fire since it only does so if you change the column. You could try to capture the key used to leave the cell. My guess is that the OnKeyDown event occurs before any of these 2 events.

If I understood your needs right, you will need to treat the last column differently in your event handlers.

Hope that helps,

Best regards

Comment: I dont think you understand the problem. If I leave the last column of the record by pressing the down arrow the FocusRecordChanged fires and the FocusItemChanged event will NOT fire. If I press then return key both events fire. I need to know in the FocusRecordChanged event if the FocusItemChanged event is due to fire.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify my statement about leaving the last column.

Comment: The whole point of asking the question is to avoid having to put in key and mouse trapping events to detect when the focus moves to a different cell. Obviously the grid cant handle it. I've wasted too much time on this already, not going to use cxGrid for this project

Comment: well, maybe you could try an alternative approach. Instead of trying to ignore the OnFocusedRecordChanged when the OnFocusedItemChanged is about to be fired, you could try to do the other way around. Set some internal flag in OnFocusedRecordChanged, then when OnFocusedItemChanged is executed check for the flag and depending on its value execute the code or simply unflag.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you disable both options and implement this logic yourself.  Here is the default implementation, you should just change it so that it meet your custom logic:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  ASite: TcxGridSite;
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    ASite := TcxGridSite(Sender);
    FocusNextCell(TcxGridTableView(ASite.GridView));
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1EditKeyDown(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  AEdit: TcxCustomEdit; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    FocusNextCell(TcxGridTableView(Sender));
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FocusNextCell(AView: TcxGridTableView);
var
  AColumn: TcxGridColumn;
begin
  AColumn := AView.Controller.FocusedColumn;
  if AView.Controller.FocusedRow.IsData then
  begin
    if AColumn.VisibleIndex < AView.VisibleColumnCount - 1 then
      AView.VisibleColumns[AColumn.VisibleIndex + 1].Focused := True
    else
      if AView.Controller.FocusNextRecord(AView.Controller.FocusedRecordIndex, True, True, False, False) and AView.Controller.FocusedRecord.HasCells then
        AView.VisibleColumns[0].Focused := True;
  end
  else
    if AView.Controller.FocusNextRecord(AView.Controller.FocusedRecordIndex, True, True, False, False) and AView.Controller.FocusedRecord.HasCells then
      AView.VisibleColumns[0].Focused := True;
  AView.Controller.EditingController.ShowEdit();
end;
```